# Inconsistant border-radius results

Tags: css

Having issues getting consistent border-radius results in Safari and Chrome. Firefox is fine.

The following will not produce any border radius in Safari or Chrome:

```
.hero-wrapper {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 429px;
border-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-top-left-radius: 0;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-top-left-radius: 0;
overflow: hidden
```

}

Ironic, simply using 'border-radius' without -moz or -webkit on other items in my DOM, work across all browsers... So confused. I checked out a few other posts on Stackoverflow and read about a bug in a previous version of Safari, but mine is up to date and is also creating issues on Chrome.

Here's the other border-radius code that's working across all browsers:

```
.hero-cta:before, .nav-wrapper:before, .nav-wrapper:after, #feature-slider:after {
position: absolute;
content: "";
border-radius: 100px;
box-shadow: rgba(212,212,212,100) 550px 50px 150px;
width: 420px;
height: 300px;
opacity: .8
```

}

Here's a link to the dev site: http://www.plasticmonument.com/biomechaniks/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing semicolons at the end of some of your css rules, so those may or may not work depending on where they are positioned. For example, your css overflow and opacity rules are missing semicolons. Second, chrome has support for unprefixed border radius [based on this fiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/wHCFA/6/). That means that you don't need to type the webkit prefixes because they just waste space in the code and bloat the whole css file in size.

Comment: Semicolons aren't required on the last declaration :)

Comment: it is proper to have them Justin, and it may be a problem in some browsers and or in the future.

Comment: Could you share documentation on that? Every W3C example omits the last semicolon. It's only necessary for starting a new declaration. If it's your last, it doesn't matter. Single declaration selectors are all over W3C, none of them have semicolons. Not to mention, adding them doesn't seem to fix my problem.

Comment: I didn't say it would fix your problem, i said it might depending on where you are missing them. Second I showed you that you don't need webkit prefixes anymore, which fixes the problem in my jsfiddle above.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of how you use those flying images on the site, apply the border to the images  instead of the div and it will be the way you want it to be.